# Does history.pushState re-define variables on page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm using `history.pushState()` in my wordpress site to changes the url/title of the page once a new post is dynamically loaded (AJAX). I want to store each post's id in an array, but for some reason the array variable gets re-defined.

At the top of my page I define the array variable:

```
<?php $array = array(); ?>
```

So when I push data to the array it only pushes to index 0.

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`pushState` changes only the history stack.

It doesn't change any other variable accessible to JavaScript.

It couldn't possibly change any PHP variable because it runs on the client and does not trigger any HTTP request.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That was my thoughts exactly, but I have no other theory why the variable will reset itself. I think the page as a whole is getting "refreshed" each time history.pushState is called, but again, this is just a theory.

Comment: `history.pushState` won't do that. Something else you do at the same time you call `pushState` might, but there isn't enough code in the question to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side and is evaluated once and for all on each load. Hence why it is 0.

As @Quentin says in his answer: `history.pushState` is JavaScript (front-end). It has no connection with PHP (back-end) whatsoever.